# Avoiding Returning Wildcard Types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, generic-collections

I have a class with a collection of Wildcard Types that is a singleton, something like:

```
public ObliviousClass{

    private static final ObliviousClass INSTANCE = new ObliviousClass();

    private Map<Key, Type<?>> map = new HashMap<Key, Type<?>>();

    public void putType(Key key, Type<?> type){
        map.put(type);
    }

    // returns the singleton
    public static ObliviousClass getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

I'd like to be able to add different Parameterized types to this collection in client code:

```
void clientMethod(){
    ObliviousClass oc = ObliviousClass.getInstance();

    Type<Integer> intType = ...
    Type<String> stringType = ...

    oc.putType(new Key(0), intType);
    oc.putType(new Key(1), stringType);
}
```

Up to this point, as I understand it, everything is ok. But a client also needs to be able to get a `Type<?>` provided the `Key`. So a method something like the following would be added to `ObliviousClass`:

```
public Type<?> getType(Key key){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

But in my handy copy of [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), I read:

> Do not use wildcard types as return types.

I understand the issue, as the client would have to cast the returned `Type<?>`. But I really do not want to make `ObliviousClass` a generic type, `ObliviousClass<T>`, because then my client code above would not work...

**Is there a better design for what I am trying to do?** 
-My current solution is to provide a static method for the client; something along the lines of:

```
public static <T> void getType(ObliviousClass instance, Key key, Type<T> dest){
    dest = (Type<T>)instance.getType(key);
}
```

I searched around, but wasn't able to find an answer that totally cleared my confusion.

Comment: have you considered adding a generic type to your class like so `ObliviousClass<T>`?

Comment: Doing that would inhibit me from adding both a Type<Integer> and Type<String> to the collection. The class Type<T> has a generic type to allow the clients some necessary flexibility in using it, but ObliviousClass is only responsible for maintaining a reference to each and does not do anything with them, directly. So maintaining them as wildcard types seems appropriate to me, but retrieving them is my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a type-safe way to store multiple instances of a given type in a map. The key is that you need to provide a `Class` instance when retrieving values in order to perform runtime type-checking, because static type information has been erased.

```
class ObliviousClass {

  private final Map<Key, Object> map = new HashMap<Key, Object>();

  public Object put(Key key, Object value)
  {
    return map.put(key, value);
  }

  public <T> T get(Key key, Class<? extends T> type)
  {
    return type.cast(map.get(key)); 
  }

}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
oc.put(k1, 42);
oc.put(k2, "Hello!");
...
Integer i = oc.get(k1, Integer.class);
String s = oc.get(k2, String.class);
Integer x = oc.get(k2, Integer.class); /* Throws ClassCastException */
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. What are the advantages to this over my static method above? Also, I want to store Parameterized types, so wouldn't the client code have to look something like: `oc.get(k1, Type<Integer>.class);`. Does that even work?

Comment: It won't work with parameterized types, because (due to erasure of type parameters) you can't get the `Class` instance you would need. If you extend `Type<T>`, providing the type parameter in your extension (e.g., `class IntegerType extends Type<Integer> {...}`) then the type parameter (`Integer`, in this example, is not erased, and you can get at it via reflection to perform the cast. This is called a "super type token." However, there are some problems with this approach; see [Neal Gafter's blog](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply type your class:

```
public ObliviousClass <T> {

    private Map<Key, Type<T>> map = new HashMap<Key, Type<T>>();

    public void putType(Key key, Type<T> type){
        map.put(type);
    }

    public Type<T> getType(Key key){
        map.get(key);
    }
}
```

FYI, at this point you have the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) in play.

Your example client code would need to declare *two* instances of `ObliviousClass`: `ObliviousClass<String>` and `ObliviousClass<Integer>`.

#### Edit:

If you *must* have a mixed bag of Types, you can impose a type on your method, but you'll get a compiler warning for an unsafe cast:

```
public class ObliviousClass {

    private final Map<Key, Type<?>> map = new HashMap<Key, Type<?>>();

    public void putType(Key key, Type<?> value) {
       map.put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Type<T> getType1(Key key, Class<T> typeClass) {
       return (Type<T>)map.get(key); 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Type<T> getType2(Key key) {
        return (Type<T>) map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Clients can type the calls to these methods like this:

```
Type<Integer> x = obliviousClass.getType1(key, Integer.class);
Type<Integer> y = obliviousClass.<Integer>getType2(key);
```

Take your pick as to which one you prefer and use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is what I'm trying to avoid. I want one single class, `ObliviousClass`, that can even potentially be a singleton, to hold a collection of `Type<?>` and not care what the actual parameterized types that are held are.

Comment: Can you help me understand the problem with having a mixed bag of Types? It seems perfectly reasonable, given that the ObliviousClass doesn't care what the actual parameterized type is and is only responsible for providing them to the clients when they ask for them. Please let me know if I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: If the client cares about the type, then ObliviousClass should too - it exists for clients to use and to meet their needs.

Comment: Also, check out latest version of code for other options and how you can call them

Answer (score 0):

For those landing on this question these many years later, this is not how Java generics are designed to be used. (I was going to comment but had more to details.)

The generic pattern manages a *single* parent class per type ID rather than multiple different classes. If we consider the simpler List<T>, a list of strings OR integers (as List<String> or List<Integer>) is how generics are defined. One class per type. This way, there is a consistent type when the values are referenced. Storing unrelated types would be the same as List<Object>. Only the programmer can know when multiple types are stored and how to retrieve them with casting.

It would be ok to store subclasses to a parent class, but when accessed from the collection without casting, the parent class contact is all that is known. For instance, a generic collection defined with an interface like Map<String, Runnable>. However, only the run() method is visible even if other public methods are added to implementations (unless the programmer explicitly casts). To access additional methods, casting is necessary.

This is a limitation in Java.  A language could be defined to know the L-Value type - even Java. But it wasn't. When new features are added, there are many backward compatible considerations [Sun and] Oracle take into account. Code compiled with generics was designed to run on older JVMs with type erasure. Java uses type erasure at compile time once it has determined that the generics are consistently reference. The bytecode uses Object as if the instance was (sort of) defined as List. If the choice was made to abandon backward compatibility, like Java 9 and 11, then multiple types *might* have been workable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ObliviousClass`, by design, doesn't know the parameterized type of the item it holds. So to be type safe, you should avoid such design :-\

But if you want to keep it, first things is that you will have to cast. There is no way out of this. But the way you do it is very error prone. For example:

```
oc.put(k1, intType);
oc.put(k2, strType);
Type<Integer> tint = oc.get(k1, Integer.class)
Type<String>  tstr = oc.get(k1, String.class)  // typo in k2: compile fine
```

And worst, due to type erasure, it will fail at runtime only once you actually use `tstr`, not when you get it from `ObliviousClass`.

So you can improve safety by tracking the parameterized type in some other way. For example, you could associate the key to the type, not losing it:

```
@Value // lombok
class Key<T> {
    private int index;
}

class Type<T> {}

class ObliviousClass {

    // side note: static final can be public safely
    public static final ObliviousClass instance = new ObliviousClass();

    private List<Type<?>> map = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T> Key<T> appendType(Type<T> type){
        // here, I found it nicer that obliviousClass generates and return the key
        // otherwise use:  "public <T> void appendType(key<T> key, Type<T> type)"
        // that binds parametrized type of both key and type arguments
        map.add(type);
        return new Key<>(map.size() - 1);
    }


    public <T> Type<T> get(Key<T> key){
        return (Type<T>) map.get(key.index);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it such as:

```
    Type<Integer> intType = new Type<>();
    Type<String>  strType = new Type<>();
    Key<Integer> k1 = ObliviousClass.instance.appendType(intType);
    Key<String>  k2 = ObliviousClass.instance.appendType(strType);

    Type<Integer> t1 = ObliviousClass.instance.get(k1);
    Type<String>  t2 = ObliviousClass.instance.get(k2);
    Type<String>  t3 = ObliviousClass.instance.get(k1); // won't compile
```