# C# Dictionary of generic classes

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, wildcard

I am new to C#.  I am trying to implement a Dictionary in C# whose Java-equivalent is:

```
HashMap<string, Variable<?>> dictionary
```

Here is the detailed Java version of what I'm trying to do: [Java how to manage user-defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468835/java-how-to-manage-user-defined-variables)

In C# so far I have something like this:

```
interface IVariable { }

public class Variable<T> : IVariable
{
    public T myValue { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, IVariable> vars = new Dictionary<string, IVariable>();
```

Then I try to do this:

```
Variable<int> age = new Variable<int>();
age.myValue = 12;
vars.Add("age", age);
IVariable theVar;
if (vars.TryGetValue("age", out theVar) {
   Console.WriteLine("fetched age is " + theVar.myValue);
}
```

I run into trouble in the last line because the compiler doesn't recognize the `myValue` member of a `theVar` because it is an `IVariable`.

In this simple example maybe I could declare `theVar` to be a `Variable<int>` instead of an `IVariable` but I haven't tried it because it would require a priori knowledge about what kind of variable I'm fetching from the dictionary and I might not always have that knowledge.

I wouldn't mind if `myValue` were an inherited/abstract property (if there is such a thing), since every Variable will have a property named `myValue` (each will differ in type but not in name).  In that case I guess I could make `IVariable` an `abstract class` rather than an `interface`, but then I still run into trouble as far as what to put for the type of `myValue`.

Could I do a cast of `theVar` into something using `as` by first checking its type with `is`?  I'm not sure if that would work or is even possible.

I've looked at these posts for guidance (especially the second one):

[Wildcard equivalent in C# generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574977/wildcard-equivalent-in-c-sharp-generics)

[C# Generics: wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283349/c-sharp-generics-wildcards)

However, my situation is still slightly different than the second example above because that example has an abstract method that is returning a void whereas I wish to have my variables return non-void generic values.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using boxing/unboxing and came up with this solution.  It appears to work... so far.  But it doesn't seem very safe.

```
public interface Variable
{
    object getValue();
    void setValue(object value);
    Type myType();
}

public class Variable<T>: Variable
{
    private T myValue;

    public object getValue() 
    {
        return myValue;
    }

    public void setValue(object value)
    {
        myValue = (T)value;
    }

    public Type myType() { return myValue.GetType(); }
}

    Dictionary<string, Variable> vars = new Dictionary<string, Variable>();

    Variable<int> age = new Variable<int>();
    age.setValue(21);
    vars.Add("age", age);
    Variable theAgeVar;
    vars.TryGetValue("age", out theAgeVar);
    Console.WriteLine("age = " + theAgeVar.getValue());

    Variable<double> height = new Variable<double>();
    height.setValue(5.9);
    Variable theHeightVar;
    vars.TryGetValue("age", out theHeightVar);
    Debug.Log("height = " + theHeightVar.getValue());
```

This prints:

age = 21

height = 5.9

One thing I do not like is that I had to make the return type of `getValue()` be an `object`.  If I wanted `myValue` (which is of type `T`) to implement `IComparable`, for instance, then this information is lost when the boxing happens and the caller receives an `object`.

Answer (score 2):

C# has [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx). You can create `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`

Or you can use object ([boxing/unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)) `Dictionary<string, object>`

Or you can get [generic type from class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx)

```
class MyClass<TDicValue>
{
    Dictionary<strint, TDicValue> myDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use dynamic because I'm using Unity and dynamic isn't supported.  So I tried using boxing/unboxing.  I posted my solution below, please take a look and let me know if it will work.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using Unity, please try it yourself. Also you may do it with generic type coming from class declaration.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean for that to sound like I was asking you to type it in and test it for me!  I worded that poorly.  What I meant was, could you take a look at my post and see what you think of the solution?  I did type it into Unity and test it and it does work.  But just because code works doesn't mean it's bulletproof.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem where I had 20 slightly different types and I had to keep dictionaries on. I wanted to organize them in a list.

The problem was the same, selecting the right kind from the list with reflection or strings lacked the ability to provide a type to return to. @skrilmps answer is correct, but packing and and unpacking was at best unreliable without a lot (metric ton) of ugly messy code.

While unity does support dynamics in 2020, this doesn't exactly work with what i am doing unless I make like everything dynamic safe and that's shamble coding, not extensible or maintainable, and just sounds like a general nightmare.

I personally feel that I am an inadequate programmer after years of trying to learn and still not having my efforts provide a productive return or product of note, so i cannot claim the answer being mine, but in my research on the proper solution to this problem i found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7qwuFnyIpM

In here he says basically if you add an interface to your similar classes that are intended for use in a variety of different lists, that you can instead make a list of that type of interface. I would assume dictionary as well, and then you can add any kind of class implementing this interface to this singular interface type defined list.

Comment: Darrell, I believe we all feel like inadequate programmers at times, don't sell yourself short. ;)

Answer (score 1):

// The following should resolve the boxing problem and now is totally generic:

```
public interface IVariable<T>
{
    T GetContent();
    void SetContent(T value);
    Type GetDataType();
}

public class Variable<T> : IVariable
{
    private T content;

    public T GetContent()
    {
        return content;
    }

    public void SetContent(T value)
    {
        content = value;
    }

    public Type GetDataType() { return GetType(); }
}

Dictionary<string, Variable<T>> variables = new Dictionary<string, Variable<T>>();
```